# Generate a Flat File from a View in Oracle DB

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

We have a view in the Oracle Database which looks like

```
HEADER,P,Lab,16-Dec-16,MEMBER,1,134,134,1,5,BENEFIT,1,MEA,1,TRAILER,          ,20161216,14:08:51
HEADER,P,Lab,16-Dec-16,MEMBER,1,134,134,1,5,BENEFIT,1,DEN,2,TRAILER,          ,20161216,14:08:51
HEADER,P,Lab,16-Dec-16,MEMBER,2,572,572,2,5,BENEFIT,2,DEN,2,TRAILER,          ,20161216,14:08:51
HEADER,P,Lab,16-Dec-16,MEMBER,2,572,572,2,5,BENEFIT,2,MEA,1,TRAILER,          ,20161216,14:08:51
```

Each record has header which keeps repeating and has the same information. Then the each MEMBER has 'n' no.of Benefits example

Member (Employee ID -1)

```
 MEMBER,1,134,134,1,5
```

has benefits (for the Employee ID-1)

```
BENEFIT,1,MEA,1
BENEFIT,1,MEA,1
```

I am trying to generate the flat file like

```
HEADER,P,Lab,16-Dec-16   //--- Header
MEMBER,1,134,134,1,5    //--- Member (Employee ID -1)
BENEFIT,1,MEA,1        //--- Benefits (Employee ID -1)
BENEFIT,1,DEN,2       // --- Benefits (Employee ID -1)
MEMBER,2,572,572,2,5 //--- Member (Employee ID -2)
BENEFIT,2,DEN,2     //--- Benefits (Employee ID -2)
BENEFIT,2,MEA,1    // --- Benefits (Employee ID -2)
TRAILER,Total no.of lines,20161216,14:08:51 // Trailer
```

I am not sure how to create the schema for the output file. Do I have to create create separate schema's for Header Member Benefits and Trailer. Or create one schema with multiple records for Header Member Benefits and Trailer. Iam not sure how to proceed. Any help with this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you alter the view to generate output closer to what you want or to output XML directly?  If not, you need to create your Oracle schema, your flat file schema, and some kind of map to transform them.  In XSLT this would almost definitely require custom XSLT to do Muenchian Grouping; alternatively, you could do it in .NET using `XDocument` or serialization...

Comment: @DanField How to output XML directly from the View. Is there a way. If there is a way to output XML can I consume directly in BizTalk

Comment: See for example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1600 - but note that you'd need proper permissions to create a SQL view or procedure on the Oracle DB itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Member table with employeeid and memberid and then Benefits table with Benefits id and memberid and have a primary key foreign key relationship to join all of them together.

Hopefully that works.

Comment: I am asking about the schema's in the BizTalk.